# runtime.getruntime().exec("wscript.exe macro.vbs") doesn't work on windows server 2008

Tags: java, tomcat, runtime, exec

I have a web application on a server deployed in tomcat 7 on windows server 2008. 
This web application is running these lines of code:

```
String path = req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "WEB-INF/vbs/macro.vbs"; 
int range = 1; 
int range1 = 1; 
int status = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript.exe" + path + "" + range + "" + range1 + "" + temp.getAbsolutePath() + "" + temp1.getAbsolutePath()).waitFor();
```

On the local computer, the execution succeeds perfectly. Deployed to the server, instead, the application stops on the exec runtime and the browser waits for a response. 
What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but still worth replying in case that someone with a similar problem.

Executing external programs using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is perfectly fine but in this case there were no spaces in between the parameters, meaning that the command to be executed was `wscript.exe/WEB-INF/vbs/macro.vbs11...` instead of `wscript.exe /WEB-INF/vbs/macro.vbs 1 1 ...`.

The `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String)` method automatically splits the string by spaces so another potential problem is that arguments in the command string might need to be wrapped in quotes to prevent them from being parsed incorrectly by the application.

The correct code would have been:

```
int status = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
   "wscript.exe \"" + path + "\" " + range + " " + range1 + "\" " + 
   temp.getAbsolutePath() + "\" " + temp1.getAbsolutePath() + "\"")
.waitFor();
```

The fact that it worked in some servers but not in others could very well be related to the paths where these files were deployed having or not having spaces in them (e.g. "C:\Program Files").